# .NET - Protecting the Flowdocument from the System.Windows.Automation

Tags: .net, ui-automation, flowdocument, ui-spy

How can I view FlowDocument read-only, that make it impossible to access the content of the document by System.Windows.Automation?

There is a [small program](http://www.automationspy.com/products.html) that uses Automation and can display the text of the document, whether it belongs to avoid?

Comment: What do you mean view FlowDocument read only in terms of UI Automation? Are you coding as a provider or as a client of UI Automation? What do you mean by belongs to avoid?

Comment: @o_weisman I think he meant avoid **copying** of text-content.

Comment: I present secret documents,
I blocked a normal copy with Ctrl + c,
But Automation Spy able to access and copy the text.